# ng-class is not toggling class on/off

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an item that is supposed to toggle a class on/off when the path changes, but for some reason it isn't working. I copied and pasted it from another project and it works there but for some reason it isn't working here.

Here is the controller:

```
app.controller('AdminNav', function($scope, $location){

    // Highlight navigation links
    $scope.isActive = function(viewLocation){
        var regexp = new RegExp(viewLocation + ".+");
        return regexp.test($location.path());
    };
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="admin-side-nav" ng-controller="AdminNav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/dashboard')}">
            <a href="/dashboard"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/dashboard/clicks')}">
            <a href="/dashboard/clicks"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></i> Clicks</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/dashboard/uploads')}">
            <a href="/dashboard/uploads"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i> Uploads</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/dashboard/forms')}">
            <a href="/dashboard/forms"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Forms</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click on one of the links the url changes, but the `active` class stays on the first `li`, and I am not sure why... Any thoughts?

Here is all of the javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('EDAdmin', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    // Prepare for html5 mode
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    // Setup routing
    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard/', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/default.html'
    }).when('/dashboard/clicks', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/default.html'
    }).when('/dashboard/uploads', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/default.html'
    }).when('/dashboard/forms', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/default.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/dashboard'
    });
});


app.controller('AdminNav', function($scope, $location){
    $scope.active = '';

    // Highlight navigation links
    $scope.isActive = function(viewLocation){
        var regexp = new RegExp(viewLocation + ".+");
        return regexp.test($scope.active);
    };

    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
        $scope.active = $location.path();
    })
});
```

Comment: Why regexp when you can directly test for $location.path() with a simple `===`?

Comment: Because there might be other things after the passed in path such as an id of some sort

Comment: [`$location.path()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) just gives the path, and not any query string params...if you want only that use `$location.search()`...if you want entire url `$location.absUrl()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you construct incorrect regular expression. For example when you click the second item regular expression will be

```
/\/dashboard\/clicks.+/
```

while the location path is

```
/dashboard/clicks
```

Obviously because of `.+` regexp doesn't match the given path but indeed matches `/dashboard`.

Much more reliable solution is to use `regexp` property of the current `$route.current` object which is used by Angular internally for exactly this purpuse - route to location path mapping:

```
$scope.isActive = function(viewLocation) {
    if ($route.current && $route.current.regexp) {
        return $route.current.regexp.test(viewLocation);
    }
    return false;
};
```

If you log `$route.current.regexp` for `/dashboard/clicks` route you will see that it looks like this:

```
/^\/dashboard\/clicks$/
```

so you can see the difference - you need to restrict string match to `^` beginning and `$` end of the string.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/7N0MQDYNWjo18bcmfIDB?p=preview

Comment: how would I match something if it comes after clicks such as: `/dashboard/clicks/something`

Comment: After click new digest cycle will run which will update bindings, and also retest all the menu items to select proper one. If this is what you are asking.

Comment: I would like it so I can place an id or a sub item of clicks after the first two items if that makes sense, and if it is dynamic I can't write a case for every type of thing

Comment: I figured out my issue, I need to use `.*` instead of `.+`, because the other project always had something after the second item, where this project doesn't. If you have something that will work the same let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Check your return value from the `$scope.isActive` method what it is returning.

Check the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eOxLEFP45zRUrzAUadXZ?p=preview)